# azure devops test plans feature level requirements based test suites

Tags: azure-devops, test-plan

My team are using the following structure for our tickets:

Feature
> Product Backlog item
> Test cases (Tested By)

were currently creating a test plan for each sprint, using requirements based test suites based on the PBI's that go in the given sprint.

Creating the test suites in this manner creates a test suite for each pbi then automatically pulls in the test cases associated to the PBI's in the the sprint.

We're trying to make use of the same functionality to create a higher level release master test plan which uses the features as test suites.

Is it possible to create  requirements based suite using the PBI's associated to a feature which then pulls the test cases associated to each pbi?

Ive tried using a query to pull in the PBIs on a feature but this does not pull in the test cases associated to each PBI.

I suspect this is because there is no direct link between the test cases and the feature.

If possible id like to avoid having to link test cases to a PBI and also to a feature as it seems like unnecessary duplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to create requirements based suite using the PBI's associated to a feature which then pulls the test cases associated to each pbi?

No, it's not supported.

When you create the requirements based suite, you can only pick one item from the query result(either Feature, or PBI...etc.), each test case that you add to a requirement-based test suite is automatically linked to the item you selected. If you choose feature, the test case is not associated to the PBI. Or if you choose PBI, test case is not associated to the Feature.